# Not able to use getElementsById in vba for web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I need to get this number 13 from a website

**HTML code**

```
<span style="margin-left:5px;" class=" list_row_number_input ">
to
<span id="listv2_57f91170dba598d00f1eef92ca9619fb_last_row" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right:1px">10</span>
of
<span id="listv2_57f91170dba598d00f1eef92ca9619fb_total_rows" style="margin-left: 1px;">13</span></span>
```

Some of the issues here:

1. The id's changes after every refresh, so I'm not able to use getElementsById
2. Also, Not able to use getElementsByClassName. I get a run time error 91, Object variable or with block variable not set

**VBA Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim name As Object

    With http
        .Open "GET", "website", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Set name = html.getElementsByClassName("list_row_number_input")(1)
Range("A6").value=name.innerText
End Sub
```

Please suggest how to handle this situation and get the required value in excel.
Thank you.

Comment: Check with `Debug.Print html.getElementsByClassName("list_row_number_input").Length` how many elements the HTML collection has. If there are too many, you will first need a larger HTML snippet to narrow down your target. Once you have found the correct span tag with the CSS class `list_row_number_input`, you must access the second span tag within this HTML section. It contains the 13.

Comment: This part: `html.getElementsByClassName("list_row_number_input")(1)` gets the **second** element from the collection of elements that have a class attribute equal to `list_row_number_input`. Is that what you want? It's not evident from the HTML snippet you posted whether there are other elements in that collection.

Comment: @StavrosJon That's a good point. I took it for granted that the indexing was clear. But that was an assumption that is not clear at all.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried  to get the length,and the value returned was 0, I'm not sure exactly why 0 was returned. Regarding the collections, I copied the full XPath and got this result : /html/body/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/div[5]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/span[1]/div/span[2]. So how do I access the second element under list_row_number_input? Is there any other way I can access it?

Comment: Get the response text and have a look. You may be dealing with a dynamic page where the required HTML code is loaded later. In this case you cannot access it with XMLHTTP60. So only what the server returns as first HTML output is fetched.

Comment: So is there any way I could fetch from a dynamic web page?

Comment: If the page works in the Internet Explorer you can use the IE to scrape from dynamic pages. If not you can use Selenium: https://www.selenium.dev/

Comment: The page works in Internet Explorer. It would be helpful if you could give a sample in my scenario, since I'm working on this for the first time, and all my attempts are not yielding the result.Thank you

Comment: You can still use id as a locator if this portion `_total_rows` remains unchanged. Given that this is how you can `HTML.querySelector("span[id*='_total_rows]").innerText`.

Comment: I get the run time error object variable or with block variable not set. Since its a dynamic webpage could you let me know how should I proceed.